# Getting 'module is not defined' after webpack build when running in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

AFter building my typescript-react application, I am getting a 'module is not defined'error after running in browser.

Note that I am targeting the electron-renderer. Everything seems to work fine when running using `èlectron .`, but when I serve it in the browser, it starts showing this error.

```
var path = require("path")
var webpack = require("webpack")

module.exports = {
    debug: true,
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    entry: {
        index: ["index.tsx", "babel-polyfill", "ts-helpers"]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
        filename: "[name].js",
        libraryTarget: "commonjs2"
    },
    resolve: {
        root: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, "src")
        ],
        extensions: ["", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { 
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loaders: [
                    "babel-loader",
                    "ts-loader"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loaders: [
                    "babel-loader"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loaders: [
                    "json-loader"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
        })
    ],
    target: "electron-renderer"
}
```